# PHP preg_match regex to find letters numbers and spaces?

Tags: php, regex

When people sign up to my site I validate their names with this code:

```
if (preg_match("[\W]", $name))
{
    $mess = $mess . "Your name must contain letters only.<br>";
    $status = "NOTOK";
}
```

This is because your actual name cannot contain symbols unless your parents were drunk when they named you.

However, this regex doesn't detect spaces. How can I fix it?

Comment: Well you need to read [this](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). Some people do have "symbols" like `'` or `-` or even a space. BTW `\W` does match a space

Comment: Careful, you might piss off a lot of irishmen named O'Reilly. And you don't want to piss off drunk Irish people!

Comment: What characters do you want to allow exactly? English letters, numbers and space?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
^[\w ]+$
```

This matches any combinations of word characters `\w` and spaces , but as the guys said be careful because some names might contain other symbols.

So you can use it like this:

```
if (preg_match("/^[\\w ]+$/", $name)) {
    // valid name
}
else {
    // invalid name
}
```

Comment: The pattern `^[\\w ]$` matches `w`(one time) and nothing else!

Comment: @Programmer.zip Thank you, this was a typo, as you can see my original pattern included the `+` symbol, but I forgot it in the code snippet. Thank you again.

Comment: Yo must NOT use two backslashes, and you must use `\s` instead of space character in the regexp.

Comment: @Programmer.zip `\s` matches many space characters such as tabs `\t`, carriage returns `\r`, new lines `\n` ... etc, and we don't need all of that. On the other hand, `\` has special meaning inside PHP strings and it has special meaning inside regular expressions, so you need to double escape to get things correct.

Comment: @Programmer.zip Thank you for correcting me for the second time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

    $user_input = 'User_name';

    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9_\s]+$/i', $user_input)) {
        // Matches English letters, numbers underscores(_) and spaces

        $mess = $mess . "Your name must contain letters only.<br>";
        $status = "NOTOK";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just missed regexp separators. I do this sometimes even after 10 years of programming.

```
if (preg_match("/[\W]/", $name)) ...
```

Comment: Those are called *delimiters*. Normally you would go for a forwardslash `/`, others may use the following characters `!#~`. The less known method is to use `[]` or `()`, it's *valid* but something valid doesn't mean we should use it -- it's confusing.